# Melhor forma de utilizar e Instanciar o EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Meu projeto possui a seguinte estrutura:

[image: pacotes do projeto]

Dentro do pacote `br.mandacaru.DAO` estão os *controllers*. Para instanciar um objeto `JPAController` eu preciso de um objeto `EntityManagerFactory` e por essa razão criei uma classe `EntityManagerProvider` que possui um método `getEntityManagerFactory` que retorna um objeto `EntityManagerFactory`. Sempre que estou instanciando um *controller*, instancio a classe `EntityManagerProvider` dentro da *view* para executar qualquer uma das ações CRUD. Ficando da seguinte maneira:

[image: Insert]

Acontece que dessa forma, para cada *View* eu vou precisar instanciar na classe o objeto `EntityManagerFactory` o que de acordo com que o projeto estiver crescendo vai ficar dispendioso e creio que não muito eficiente. Qual seria a melhor maneira de instanciar esse objeto `EntityManagerFactory` na classe main e passá-lo para as views?

Comment: Minha sugestão para esse caso é usar o padrão **Singleton**. Se a classe `EntityManagerProvider` for uma fachada sua, fica mais fácil implementar o **Singleton** nela. Caso contrário terá que criar uma classe para implementar esse padrão.

Comment: @Wakim A classe EntityManagerProvider eu mesmo criei e estou vendo sobre Singleton agora. Realmente pode ser a solução. Vou testar.

Comment: Para a utilização, eu criaria uma solução para Injetar o EntityManager onde fosse necessário. Em sistemas mais simples é totalmente desnecessário, mas para aplicações mais complexas ajuda a desacoplar o sistema de uma classe específica, o código fica um pouquinho mais limpo e as chances de ocorrerem erros em tempo de execução é menor, já que os objetos ou *proxies* são injetados antes do método começar a executar. Fora de um servidor de aplicação é fácil conseguir isso usando Spring, por exemplo, mas também dá para usar CDI usando o Weld.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EntityManagerFactory pode e deve ser estático:

1. Na especificação diz que ele é multi-thread
2. Custo '*muito alto*' para você instanciá-lo tempo todo

Na classe que você criou, deixe o EntityManagerFactory como `private static EntityManagerFactory emf`. Depois crie um método estático como:

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

EntityManager não é thread safe:

1. A especificação diz que ele não deve ser reutilizado
2. O ideal é, abrir um quando o request chegar e depois finalizar.
3. Se deixá-lo aberto, os recursos com o banco de dados podem se esgotar

Answer (score 5):

Eis aqui as regras de ouro:

1. Você deve ter um `EntityManager` por interação com o banco de dados<sup>1</sup>.
2. Você deve ter um `EntityManagerFactory` por base de dados na aplicação (*persistence unit*) e por `ClassLoader`.

A maioria das aplicações não lida com `ClassLoader`s diretamente e não precisa lidar com múltiplas versões de uma mesma classe em memória ao mesmo tempo. Portanto em 99,9% dos casos, a regra número 2 pode ser simplificada para:

2. Você deve ter um `EntityManagerFactory` por base de dados na aplicação (*persistence unit*).

Além disso, em uns 98% dos casos, a aplicação só trabalha com uma única base de dados. E portanto, a regra número 2 pode ser simplificada para:

2. Você deve ter um único `EntityManagerFactory` na aplicação.

E isto sugere que você pode usar o padrão de projeto **singleton**:

```java
public final class EntityManagerProvider {

    private static final EntityManagerProvider INSTANCE = new EntityManagerProvider();

    private final EntityManagerFactory factory;

    private EntityManagerProvider() {
        this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SUA_BASE_DE_DADOS");
    }

    public static EntityManagerProvider getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public EntityManager createManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Esta classe acima cuida da regra 2 perfeitamente. Sugiro você implementar a regra número 1 nela também, usando um `ThreadLocal` para manter as referências aos `EntityManager`s e cuidando para não reutilizar `EntityManager`s de requisições diferentes, o que pode acontecer se as suas threads estiverem em um pool e puderem ser reutilizadas entre diferentes requisições.

Além disso, o código acima é fácil de ser modificado para lidar com o caso aonde há mais de uma base de dados. Basta que cada `EntityManagerFactory` esteja em um campo da classe `EntityManagerProvider` e que cada um seja acessado por um diferente conjunto de métodos, ou que você acrescente um parâmetro aos métodos pertinentes especificando qual é a base de dados relevante.

---

<sup>1 - Neste contexto, define-se por interação com o banco de dados uma sequência de operações relacionadas a ser executadas consecutivamente no banco de dados, possivelmente em um único escopo de transação.</sup>

Comment: Um EntityManager por sessão? Você poderia me passar o material de onde vc se baseou nessa prática?

Comment: @uaiHebert Troquei o termo para requisição e o defini melhor, para evitar confusão.

Comment: Ainda assim sua observação de requisição soa estranha. Se eu tiver 2 processamentos, eu devo usar então dois entityManager?

Comment: @uaiHebert Depende. De qualquer forma talvez eu não esteja me expressando direito. O foco do texto é o `EntityManagerFactory`, então eu não queria colocar mais do que um texto curto de apenas uma frase sobre o `EntityManager`. Alguma sugestão para melhorar o texto?