# Como trabalhar com o cache do JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho dúvida como devo trabalhar com os objetos `EntityManagerFactory` e `EntityManager`.

Atualmente eu instancio um `EntityManagerFactory` para todo o sistema, como tenho só um banco, crio só um mesmo e uso ele para criar meus `EntityManager`. Os `EntityManager` eu instancio geralmente um por tela, ou seja um para cada crud. Está certo essa forma de gerenciá-los?

Aí vem minha **segunda pergunta**:

Está acontecendo o seguinte:

Usuário 1 pesquisa o registro x

Usuário 2 faz uma alteração no registro x

Usuário 1 atualiza a tela e o registro x continua inalterado, como se o Usuário 2 não tivesse interagido

E no banco de dados está atualizado conforme o Usuário 2 alterou

Se eu fecho todo o sistema do Usuário 1 e reabro tá lá o registro x atualizado

Porque não atualiza para o Usuário 1? Sempre terei que criar um novo `EntityManager` para cada interação com o banco de dados?

Método que faz a pesquisa dos dados:

```
public List<Evento> getListPeriodo(Date inicio, Date fim, String texto) {
    Query query = getDbManager().createNamedQuery("Evento.getListPeriodo");

    query.setParameter("inicio", inicio);
    query.setParameter("fim", fim);
    query.setParameter("texto", "%" + texto + "%");

    List<Evento> lista = query.getResultList();
    return lista;
}
```

Trecho onde populo uma JTable com o resultado da pesquisa:

```
    EntityManager dbManager = Constante.DBFACTORYLOCAL.createEntityManager();
    dbManager.clear();
    EventoDAO EventoDAO = new EventoDAO(dbManager);
    try {
        List<Evento> oe = EventoDAO.getListPeriodo(di, de, jTextFieldFiltro.getText());

        for (Evento t : oe) {
            String cntr = "";
            for (Item o : t.getItens()) {
                if (cntr.isEmpty()) {
                    cntr = o.getPalavra();
                } else {
                    cntr = cntr + ", " + o.getPalavra();
                }
            }

            Object[] linha = new Object[]{t.getEventoId(), t.getDescricao(), cntr, DateFunction.DateUtilToTexto(t.getDataInicio())};
            modelo.addRow(linha);
        }
    } finally {
        dbManager.close();
    }
```

Comment: Possivel duplicata (ou não): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45758/melhor-forma-de-utilizar-e-instanciar-o-entitymanagerfactory

Comment: O que exatamente são as suas telas? Componentes swing? Páginas JSP? Servlets? Formulários HTML com ajax? Um monte de `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alguns métodos de obtenção de entidades resgatam a entidade da memória se ela já estiver lá, e não do banco de dados. Por exemplo, você busca uma pessoa:

```
pessoa = entityManager.find(Pessoa.Class, id);
```

daí alguém altera e persiste esta mesma pessoa e você busca novamente usando o mesmo método acima e a mesma instância do **EntityManager**. O que vai ocorrer é que você não vai obter a pessoa atualizada do banco de dados mas sim a mesma instância que você já tinha obtido na primeira chamada do **find** (a instância será resgatada da memória e não será criada uma nova a partir do banco).

Se você deseja então disponibilizar digamos um botão para o usuário refrescar as informações que ele tem na tela, você não precisa de uma nova instância do EntityManager - você pode ativamente solicitar que a instância seja atualizada com as informações do banco de dados, assim:

```
entityManager.refresh(pessoa);
```

Se o escopo do seu EntityManager é realmente reduzido e claro, você pode ser ainda mais ousado e invocar o método **clear**:

```
entityManager.clear();
```

Isso limpará completamente o contexto (esta instância do EntityManager) de modo que todas as requisições seguintes serão levadas ao banco de dados. É claro que este comando também desatachará todas as entidades deste contexto e as eventuais alterações nestas entidades serão perdidas (a não ser que você as atache novamente).

Comment: fiz um teste assim: criei o `manager = factory.createEntityManager();`, limpei `manager.clear()`, fiz a namedQuery e fechei `manager.close()`. Daí alterei um registro no banco, refiz o teste novamente e ainda sim traz a informação desatualizada. Impossível que outros sistemas tenham esse mesmo problema. E o pior, eu acompanhei o `show_sql` e ele faz as queries, só não atualiza os objetos.

Comment: @Gleison Então você terá que mostrar o seu código que altera o registro e o código que espera ler o registro atualizado.

Comment: coloquei na pergunta o trecho que faz a pesquisa e carrega no JTable, quanto a alteração no banco eu faço na mão, pois a ideia é simular que outra pessoa altere o registro, não necessariamente quem está pesquisando.

Comment: @Gleison E quando você altera na mão no banco de dados, você commita a transação antes de tentar ver os registros atualizados na tela? Veja: se você usa Oracle, por exemplo, o padrão é abrir uma transação quando você faz a primeira alteração, depois a transação fica aberta até você fechar.

Comment: Não é esse o caso, eu uso o Mysql e faço sem transação mesmo. Tanto que quando eu fecho o sistema e abro novamente os dados estão lá atualizados. Parece que o `manager.clear()` não limpa o cache conforme o Victor mencionou.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve ter um `EntityManager` por interação do banco de dados. Isso significa:

- Nunca compatilhe `EntityManager`s entre diferentes threads. Eles não projetados para serem single-thread.
- Se você reutiliza threads para tratar requisições ou interações diferentes, lembre-se de não reutilizar os `EntityManager`s.

Esse seu comportamento deve ser resultado dos [níveis de isolamento que o banco de dados oferece](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), que podem ser:

- ***Read uncommited*** - Permite que uma transação enxergue dados não commitados de outra transação (o que é chamado de *dirty read*).
- ***Read commited*** - Permite a leitura apenas de dados commitados até o momento em que a leitura é efetuada. Porém duas leituras idênticas na mesma transação em tempos diferentes podem trazer resultados diferentes para as mesmas tuplas (o que é chamado de *non-repeatable read*).
- ***Repeatable reads*** - A releitura de quaisquer dados já lidos produzirá o mesmo resultado das leituras anteriores na transação. Entretanto, dados novos inseridos por outras transações ainda podem fazer com que duas leituras idênticas produzam resultados distintos, aonde a segunda trás resultados a mais do que a primeira (o que é chamado de *phantom read*).
- ***Serializable*** - A transação só vê os dados que existiam até o momento em que ela foi iniciada do jeito que estavam quando ela foi iniciada.

O comportamento que você viu entre os usuários 1 e 2 demonstra que o hibernate deve estar usando os níveis *repeatable reads* ou *serializable*.

Para lidar com isso, você deverá verificar se o escopo das suas transações não estão nem maiores e nem menores do que o que deveriam ser, que normalmente (mas nem sempre) significa englobar a requisição por completo, sem mais nem menos (ou qualquer coisa que seja semelhante a uma requisição caso você esteja em um sistema desktop ou batch).

Você pode utilizar o método `EntityManager.clear()` para limpar qualquer cache que o hibernate fizer ao iniciar ou terminar uma transação. Além disso, ao término da transação você pode usar o `EntityManager.close()` para finalizá-lo e certificar-se de não tentar utilizar o `EntityManager` fechado novamente após isso (desde que o container ou o mecanismo de injeção de dependências já não faça isso automaticamente).

Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45784/132

Comment: Definitivamente e com certeza absoluta não é disso que se trata.

Comment: @Caffé Na verdade não sei, reli a pergunta e como não há código fiquei em dúvida. Entretanto esse trecho me faz suspeitar que o principal problema é que o OP está usando o EntityManager de forma incorreta: *Os EntityManager eu instancio geralmente um por tela, ou seja um para cada crud. Está certo essa forma de gerenciá-los?* - E foi principalmente isso que me levou a produzir esta resposta.

Comment: Não há problema em instanciar "um EntityManager por tela". Ou há?

Comment: @Caffé. Depende, o que essa "tela" é? Se for um servlet por exemplo e você instanciar um por servlet e compartilhar entre todas as requisições, já viu o que vira, né?

Comment: Por servlet pode funcionar bem também. Depende do escopo do servlet.

Comment: @Caffé. Pois é, **depende**. Ou seja, *não está claro o que você está perguntando.* - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47078/como-trabalhar-com-o-cache-do-jpahibernate/47083?noredirect=1#comment94802_47078

Answer (score 1):

## Escopo do `EntityManager`

Respondendo à primeira pergunta: manter uma instância do `EntityManager` por classe não parece correto.

Claro que isso pode funcionar em determinadas circunstâncias, como no caso da classe ser recriada a cada requisição em um sistema web, pois assim haverá um `EntityManager` novo para cada *thread* e não se incorrerá em problemas de concorrência.

Num sistema web com com acesso concorrente há duas abordagens simples que são comuns:

1. Obter um novo `EntityManager` em cada método que acessa o banco de dados. Na maioria dos casos, a criação de um `EntityManager` é rápida, em contrapartida com a criação do `EntityManagerFactory`, que só deve ser feita uma vez por `DataSource`.
2. Obter um novo `EntityManager` por *thread* ou requisição. Em rotinas mais "pesadas" isso geralmente é melhor para o desempenho, mas apresenta alguns desafios de gerenciamento. A implementação manual pode ser feita usando `ThreadLocal`.

Para evitar gastar tempo com as complexidades do gerenciamento e, ao mesmo tempo permitir mais flexibilidade no gerenciamento dos objetos, eu recomendaria o uso de algum framework de Injeção de Dependências, tal como Spring, que permite a configuração geral do `EntityManagerFactory` em um só local e a distribuição automática de instâncias do `EntityManager` onde for necessário. Uma grande vantagem é que você pode mudar o escopo do `EntityManager` da forma como quiser sem praticamente nenhum trabalho usando anotações ou configurações do framework.

## Versionamento de registros

O cenário onde dois usuários acessam a mesma tela ao mesmo tempo pode ser desmembrado em duas partes:

### Concorrência

Os usuários atuam simultaneamente e geram requisições concorrentes que executam ao mesmo tempo no servidor.

Neste caso é preciso atentar para definir blocos transacionais ACID sempre que houver múltiplos acessos ao bancos de dados dentro de uma mesma requisição, de modo a garantir a integridade e consistência dos dados no banco.

Além disso, como já discuti no tópico anterior, é preciso atentar para quaisquer objetos que possam ser indevidamente compartilhados entre as duas requisições, tal como o `EntityManager`.

O ideal é que não haja nenhum tipo de compartilhamento para garantir um paralelismo completo, sem necessidade de sincronizações.

### *Stale data* (dados defasados)

Este é o caso descrito na segunda pergunta. Consiste em que um usuário tente atuar sobre dados num estado anterior ao que existe no sistema remoto.

Existem algumas estratégias para evitar esse tipo de problema, sendo a mais comum e eficaz (embora trabalhosa) o versionamento de registros no banco de dados.

Isso significa que a ação de um usuário que afeta o estado do sistema somente será válida se ele provar que possui os dados atuais.

Pense num campo de `versao` adicionado na tabela. Por exemplo:

```
IdCliente   NomeCliente   VersaoRegistro
11          Luiz          1
```

Agora o usuário **A** abre a tela com o registro acima sendo exibido. O valor de `VersaoRegistro` é armazenado oculto na tela.

Nesse meio tempo, o usuário **B** acessa o mesmo registro e realiza uma alteração no nome. Quando o sistema recebe a requisição de atualização, ele verifica a versão enviada por **B**, que é `1`, atualiza os demais campos e incrementa a versão. Agora temos a tabela assim:

```
IdCliente   NomeCliente   VersaoRegistro
11          Luiz S.       2
```

Quando o usuário **A** tentar alterar o registro, o sistema vai verificar que a versão que **A** está tentando alterar é anterior à versão atual. O sistema então bloqueia a alteração e responde com alguma mensagem do tipo: *os dados foram alterados desde sua última consulta, por favor, tente novamente*.

O tratamento pode variar. Claro que quanto mais cedo o usuário for notificado melhor, assim ele não perde o trabalho.

Comment: Ótima resposta, embora a pergunta seja antiga. O único detalhe que vou atentar é a esse parágrafo que ficou estranho: "*Os usuários atual ao mesmo tempo e geram requisições concorrentes que executam ao mesmo tempo no servidor.*"

Comment: @VictorStafusa Muito obrigado! Está corrigido...