# Alto consumo de memória aplicação Swing Java

Tags: java, desempenho, jpa, memória

Estou em desenvolvimento de uma aplicação Java porém ao realizar alguns testes e notei que ao executar a aplicação, o meu consumo de memória aumenta. E conforme o uso, ela sempre vai alocando mais e mais memória. Não acontece de cair a memória utilizada entre o intervalo de uma aplicação com outra.

E conforme vou usando a aplicação, ela trabalha até ocorrer um estouro de memória por parte da máquina.

Ao executar o projeto utilizando a ferramenta Perfil do Netbeans, notei que a cada requisição ao banco de dados, ele abre um pool-thread e ela fica parada. Aparentemente isso parece estar aumentando meu consumo.

Gostaria de saber por onde posso começar a checar para melhorar o desempenho de minha aplicação.

Vou postar o código do processo de cadastro de produtos abaixo para que possam analisar com mais precisão:

**persistence.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SisPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Funcionario</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Pessoa</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Grupo</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Subgrupo</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Produto</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Ncm</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Tributacao</class>
    <class>br.com.Sis.modelo.Fornecedor</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Sis?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="1234"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**ConexaoJPA.java**

```java
public class ConexaoJPA {

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SisPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;   
    }
}
```

**ProdutoDAO.java**

```java
public class ProdutoDAO implements Serializable {

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return ConexaoJPA.getEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(Produto produto) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(produto);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProdutoControle.java**

```java
public class ProdutoControle {

    public void inserir(int codgrupo, int codsubgrupo, int codtribut, String codbarras, int codfornecedor, String nomeproduto, String descproduto,
                     String unicomproduto, String univendproduto,  String nomFornecedor, double qtdproduto, double qtdextproduto, double qtdemaxproduto,
                     double qtdeminproduto, double custoproduto, double valvendaproduto, double margproduto, String localproduto,
                     String tipoproduto, String finproduto, int dia_validproduto, String obsproduto, double codibptnac, double codibptimp) throws Exception {


        Produto produto = new Produto();

        produto.setCodgrupo(codgrupo);
        produto.setCodsubgrupo(codsubgrupo);
        produto.setCodtributacao(codtribut);
        produto.setCodBarproduto(codbarras);
        produto.setCodfornecedor(codfornecedor);
        produto.setNomproduto(nomeproduto);
        produto.setNomIdeproduto(descproduto);
        produto.setUniComproduto(unicomproduto);
        produto.setUniVenproduto(univendproduto);
        produto.setNomfornecedor(nomFornecedor);
        produto.setQtdproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(qtdproduto));
        produto.setQtdExtproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(qtdextproduto));
        produto.setQtdMaxproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(qtdemaxproduto));
        produto.setQtdMinproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(qtdeminproduto));
        produto.setValCusproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(custoproduto));
        produto.setValVenproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(valvendaproduto));
        produto.setMarLucproduto(BigDecimal.valueOf(margproduto));
        produto.setLocproduto(localproduto);
        produto.setTipproduto(tipoproduto);
        produto.setFinproduto(finproduto);
        produto.setDiaValproduto(dia_validproduto);
        produto.setObsproduto(obsproduto);
        produto.setCodibptnac(BigDecimal.valueOf(codibptnac));
        produto.setCodibptimp(BigDecimal.valueOf(codibptimp));


        new ProdutoDAO().create(produto);



    }
}
```

Também tenho a classe em que mapeio os campos do banco de dados que tem meus getters e setters e a visual, onde capturo os dados digitados pelo usuário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu principal problema parece estar na `ConexaoJPA`:

```java
public class ConexaoJPA {

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SisPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;   
    }
}
```

Você está utilizando o `EntityManagerFactory` e o `EntityManager` de formas um tanto inadequadas. O do `EntityManager` até não tem muito problema, pois você o fecha adequadamente, apenas falha em reutilizá-lo quando possível. Mas isso não deve lhe causar maiores problemas.

O maior problema é o `EntityManagerFactory`. Você não deveria criar múltiplas instâncias do `EntityManagerFactory`. Apenas uma que viva durante todo o escopo da aplicação deveria ser necessária.

A solução mais simples seria isso:

```java
public class ConexaoJPA {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SisPU");

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = EMF.createEntityManager();
        return em;   
    }
}
```

Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45784/132